# What is the required deadline to report an insider trade?

Tags: stocks, sec

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/844059/000147450621000165/xslF345X03/primary_doc.xml

I see the above trade was on 10/12/2021. But it was reported almost a month later 11/05/2021. Does anybody know what is the required deadline to report an insider trade?

Comment: whoops, I misread your subject as "report to the authorities" an insider trade of someone else that was suspected of being illegal!